# Class method can't access properties

Tags: javascript, class, dom-events

I have created a class like so:

```
function MyClass()
{
    var myInt = 1;
}

MyClass.prototype.EventHandler = function(e)
{
    alert(this.myInt);
}
```

Unfortunately, the `this` is the triggered event (in my case an `<a>` tag), and I can't access the class properties.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you are giving your event handler when registering the event.

The following code

```
element.addEventListener("click", myObject.EventHandler);
```

will not do what you want.

Javascript does not handle delegates like C# would for example, so myObject.EventHandler is not the EventHandler method called for myObject.

If you want to call a method on an object as an event handler, the best is to wrap it into a function.

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
    myObject.EventHandler(event);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although i had to tweak it a bit:
attaching the event was made inside the scope of the class (myObject) so myObject.EventHandler is unknown.
Instead, before attaching the event i added to the element a property with the 'this' (element.myObj=this);
and now i can access the obj

Answer (score 5):

"vars" declared in the constructor function will not be available on other public functions, they are considered as "*private members*".

You could use `this.myInt = 1` to make the member public, and available to all the class methods:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.myInt = 1;  // Public member
}

MyClass.prototype.EventHandler = function(e){
    alert(this.myInt);
}
```

or you could have a "*privileged*" method, to access the "*private*" member on the constructor scope:

```
function MyClass(){
    var myInt = 1; // Private member

    this.getMyInt = function(){  // Public getter
        return myInt;
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.EventHandler = function(e){
    alert(this.getMyInt());
}
```

Recommended lecture: [Private Members in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) (Douglas Crockford)

Comment: but doesn't the 'this' object will reference the <a> tag when the EventHandler function will be called?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't actually have classes.  `MyClass` is the constructor for an object whose prototype is the object `MyClass.prototype`.

The `this` keyword can be confusing to understand; its value in a function depends on what object the function is called as a property of.

If you want to be able to call a method of an object from an event handler, you should use a function closure like Vincent Robert suggests.

I suggest you check out these links for more information about `this`:

- http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Understanding_JavaScript's_this_keyword
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Furthermore,

```
function MyClass()
{
    var myInt = 1;
}
```

This constructor sets a local variable within the function which is not accessible from outside of the function. If you want to initialize a property of the object, you need to use `this.myInt = 1`.  This value will only be set on objects constructed by `new MyClass()`, however, and not on the MyClass function object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you replace `var myInt` with `this.myInt`, you can reference it as `MyClass.myInt` from within `MyClass.prototype.EventHandler` without worry about what `this` refers to.